# Loop URL and load using array depends on ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a string list of id's where;

```
ids = '1,2,3,4,5'
```

just a representation of div

```
<div id="item_1">Text 1 - Suspended </div>
<div id="item_2">Text 2 - Suspended </div>
<div id="item_3">Text 3 - Suspended </div>
<div id="item_4">Text 4 - Suspended </div>
```

and converted to array (if you have a better solution to convert string to array please share, tia!)

```
array_id = ids.split(',');
```

My problem is that how can I loop the url and load it into a different div with array id?

```
function multipleLoadContent(url,id){
var ids = id;
var array_id = new Array();
array_id = ids.split(',');

    // maybe loop here and apply where id is?
    $("#item_"+array_id ).load(url);
}
```

returned text is a system generated output, example

```
for id "item_1" returned text "Text 1 - Active"
for id "item_2" returned text "Text 2 - Declined"
for id "item_3" returned text "Text 3 - Stale"
.....
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to populate multipe divs with the *same* content from the *same* URL? (As an aside, note that you can do `var array_id = id.split(',');` - you don't need `new Array()` because that creates a new empty array but `.split()` creates a new array itself, and you don't need the `ids` variable, you can use the `id` function argument directly.)

Comment: No sir@nnnnnn, i had already div with their ids. I just need to load/reload the updated content. Thanks

Comment: So what does "loop the url" mean? Please [edit] your question to show what is in the `url` variable, and to clarify what you want to do with it. (Maybe you could show a *short* sample of the html.)

Comment: Can you try this?

ids.split(',').forEach(function(item){$("#item_"+item ).load(url));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a for loop to iterate over each element:

```
array_id.forEach(item) {
    $("#item_" + item).load(url);
}
```

This is a for-each loop which iterates over all elements in `array_id`. The current element's value is accessible through `item`. Consider:

```
var array_test = [1, 2, 3, 6]
array_test.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

This will log:

```
1
2
3
6
```

As expect because we loop over each element and log it.

Comment: That's not how a `for..in` loop works. (Even aside from the fact that you shouldn't use them on arrays,) the `id` variable will get the array indices, not the values.

Comment: Sorry, meant `forEach`!

Comment: log are getting the ids but load(url) didn't applied

Comment: Updated @mrrsb, forgot the underscore in the IDs!

Comment: Now I got it sir @AndrewL.

Comment: Yup! Kudos sir @AndrewL.

Comment: @mrrsb no problem! If you have any other question I'll be glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Even better, you can use forEach method.

```
ids.split(',').
forEach(function(item){
  $("#item_"+item ).load(url));
});
```